# Read Ant properties file generated by Apache FOP

Tags: ant, apache-fop

I am new to Ant. I am trying to read two property files, The first is static and second is created during the build process. Please see below.

There is one static property file which I read in at the top: `./cfg/build.properties`.

Then again reading another property file inside a target tag. The flow is described below.

There are two targets which will get executed in sequences.

First I am trying to create a property file using FOP in target GENERATE_PROPERTYFILE.

Then on the second target, READ_PROPERTY_FILE_GENERATE_XML, I am reading the property file created in the first step.

But the issue is, it is not picking a value for `${IssueObjects.ID}` from the second property file.

Below is the snapshot of script.

```
<project name="fop4ant" default="run" basedir=".">

<property file="./cfg/build.properties" prefix="System"/>
<property environment="env"/>

<tstamp>
        <format property="param_TouchTimeStamp" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmssSS"/>
</tstamp>
<property name="param_TouchTimeStamp" value=""  />

<property name="prop_File_XSL_FetchProbNSolObjects" value="${System.prop_Dir_stylesheet}/${System.prop_File_Stylesheet_FetchProbSol_CNReport}"  />

<property name="prop_File_XML" value="${System.prop_Dir_temp}/Object-${param_TouchTimeStamp}.xml"  />
<property name="prop_File_XML_Prob" value="${System.prop_Dir_temp}/Prob-${param_TouchTimeStamp}.xml"  />
<property name="prop_File_COIDs" value="${System.prop_Dir_temp}/probCO-${param_TouchTimeStamp}.properties"  />

<property name="prop_Dir_FOP" value="${env.FOP_HOME}"/>
<property name="prop_Dir_GS" value="${env.GS_HOME}"/>

<taskdef name="fop" 
         classname="org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.Fop">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${prop_Dir_FOP}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${prop_Dir_FOP}/build">
      <include name="fop.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>

    <!-- @SECTION_BEGIN :: READ_PROPERTY_FILE_GENERATE_XML -->
<target name="generate-problem-item-productview">
    <echo message="prop_XML_FILE_PROB :: ${prop_File_XML_Prob}" level="info" />
    <!--Reading dynamically created property file-->
    <property file="$prop_File_COIDs" prefix="IssueObjects"/>

    <exec executable="export.exe">
        <arg line="-xml_file=${prop_File_XML_Prob} -transfermode=${IssueObjects.ID}">
     </exec>
</target>
<!-- @SECTION_END :: READ_PROPERTY_FILE_GENERATE_XML  -->

<!-- @SECTION_BEGIN :: GENERATE_PROPERTYFILE-->
<target name="fetch-prob-sol-items">
    <echo message="prop_File_XML :: ${prop_File_XML}" level="info" />
    <echo message="prop_File_XSL_FetchProbNSolObjects :: ${prop_File_XSL_FetchProbNSolObjects}" level="info" />
    <echo message="prop_File_COIDs :: ${prop_File_COIDs}" level="info" />

    <echo message="prop_Dir_FOP :: ${prop_Dir_FOP}/fop.bat" level="info" />

    <exec executable="${prop_Dir_FOP}/fop.bat">
        <arg value="-xml"/>
        <arg value="${prop_File_XML}"/>
        <arg value="-xsl"/>
        <arg value="${prop_File_XSL_FetchProbNSolObjects}"/>
        <arg value="-foout"/>
        <arg value="${prop_File_COIDs}"/>
      </exec>
</target>
<!-- @SECTION_END :: GENERATE_PROPERTYFILE -->

<target name="run" depends="">
    <echo message="start :: run" level="info" />
    <antcall target="fetch-prob-sol-items" />
    <antcall target="generate-problem-item-productview" />
    <echo message="end :: run" level="info" />
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `READ_PROPERTY_FILE_GENERATE_XML` section, replace the following...

```
<property file="$prop_File_COIDs" prefix="IssueObjects"/>
```

...with...

```
<property file="${prop_File_COIDs}" prefix="IssueObjects"/>
```

In the above example, curly braces have been added around the `prop_File_COIDs` reference.